# react-hook-form controller adds another entry in the form data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hook-form

I am working with a programmatically generated form (from a json file) with multi steps. I followed the react-hook-form [wizard guide](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage/#WizardFormFunnel) and I combine it with nested component to create the components I need to create the form and its pages.

The problem I have is that if I wrap my component with a Controller, when I submit my form, I have two ids, one with the right id and an undefined value (which is wrong), the second with the wrong id but the right value

```js
import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker'
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form'
import styled from 'styled-components/native'
import { useState } from 'react'

type SelectFieldProps = {
  element: SurveyPageComponent
}
const SelectField = ({
  element: { options, position, defaultValue, label, type, id }
}: SelectFieldProps) => {
  const { register } = useFormContext()
  const [selectedField, setSelectedField] = useState<unknown>(defaultValue)

  return (
    <>
      <Label>{label}</Label>
      <Select
        {...register(`${id}`)}
        selectedValue={selectedField}
        onValueChange={(itemValue) => setSelectedField(itemValue)}
      >
        {options.map(({ label, id }) => (
          <Picker.Item
            key={`${type}-${position}-option-${position}-${label}-${id}`}
            label={label}
            value={id}
          />
        ))}
      </Select>
    </>
  )
}

const Label = styled.Text`
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
`

const Select = styled(Picker)`
  width: 100%;
`

export default SelectField
```

This gives me after submitting:

Object {
"6": undefined,
}

If I wrap my Input with a controller like this:

```js
import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker'
import { Controller, useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form'
import styled from 'styled-components/native'

type SelectFieldProps = {
  element: SurveyPageComponent
}
const SelectField = ({
  element: { options, position, required, defaultValue, label, type, id }
}: SelectFieldProps) => {
  const {
    control,
    register,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useFormContext()

  return (
    <>
      <Label>{label}</Label>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
          <Select
            {...register(`${id}`)}
            selectedValue={value}
            onValueChange={(itemValue) => onChange(itemValue)}
          >
            {options.map(({ label, id }) => (
              <Picker.Item
                key={`${type}-${position}-option-${position}-${label}-${id}`}
                label={label}
                value={id}
              />
            ))}
          </Select>
        )}
        name={label}
        rules={{ required }}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
      />
      {errors[`${type}-${position}-${label}`] && (
        <span>This field is required</span>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

const Label = styled.Text`
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
`

const Select = styled(Picker)`
  width: 100%;
`

export default SelectField
```

I get after submitting:

Object {
"6": undefined,
"Avez-vous apprécié ce nouveau client ?": 2,
}

I just cannot understand why would the controller adds another line to my submitted data and I didn't found an answer to this anywhere.

The only way I made it work is to add a `` setValue(`${id}`, itemValue) `` in my `onValueChange` property.

Can someone point me in the right direction please ?

Answer (score 0):

I found why, I don't need to register my field, but I need to put the correct name in my controller (in that case my id):

`` name={`${id}`} ``